# Как задать действие для кнопок свернуть/развернуть javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

С кнопкой закрыть все понятно, а как быть с кнопками свернуть/развернуть?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Q extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new javafx.geometry.Insets(55));
        //не останавливать приложение
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        Button button = new Button("Yes");
        root.getChildren().addAll(textField, button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> System.out.println("Нажат крестик"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setOnShowing(EventHandler<WindowEvent> value) 
setOnShown(EventHandler<WindowEvent> value)
setOnHiding(EventHandler<WindowEvent> value)
setOnHidden(EventHandler<WindowEvent> value)
```

ing-овые методы - событие происходит до сворачивания/разворачивания

Comment: Я может чего-то не понимаю, но у меня эти методы не работают. Можете привести код? Для кнопки свернуть.

Comment: Может импортиро6надо библеотеку